# DetailView shows only one entry of Tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, tableview, master-detail

I've got a Master-Detail Applicaton in Xcode with a TableView and a SearchDisplayController.
In the TableView I have got a NSArray with 10 entries.
If I use the Searchbar, the DetailView shows correctly the entry I clicked on.
But if I do not use the Searchbar and click in the TableView on an entry, the DetailView every time shows me the first entry of the TableView.
What can I do to fix it?

MasterViewController.m: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7fDn.png

MasterViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>  
@interface DPMasterViewController : UITableViewController  
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;  
@end
```

DetailViewController.m: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkR9C.png

DetailViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>  
@interface DPDetailViewController : UIViewController  
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;  
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;  
@end
```

Sorry that I use pictures, but I think it is easier for you to check. :)
I hope you can help me!
If anything is missing, just tell me.

EDIT:

In This Method after the else every time the indexPath.row = 0. I don't know how to fix it :(

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    DPDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;

    if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) { 
        indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        destViewController.detailItem = [searchItemList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        destViewController.detailItem = [itemList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: Could you try to describe your problem a little better?  Is the problem in the detail view, or the master view?

Comment: In my MasterView there is a SearchBar with SearchDisplayController and a TableView. If I search after an entry in the TableView (with the SearchBar) and click on this, then the View switches to DetailView and shows me a Label with the text from the entry. This part works correctly. But when I don't search with the SearchBar (I click on a Entry in the TableView) the view switches to the DetailView and the Label shows every time the text from entry number 1. -> I click on entry 2 and in the DetailView the Label shows entry 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not performing any actions when you click on a cell of the tableView that is not part of the searchDisplayController, so try to change your tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method to

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but now the app crashes and I get this error:  

`2012-07-17 22:55:11.532 APP[449:f803] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2012-07-17 22:55:11.914 APP[449:f803] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
2012-07-17 22:55:11.923 APP[449:f803] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <DPDetailViewController: 0x6e706f0>.`

Comment: How did you hook up that segue with your tableView in your Storyboard?

Comment: Push Segue from Cell to Detail. --- Identifier: showDetail  --- Style: Push

Comment: Oh ok, in that case my answer is wrong - keep your original tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method. Not sure what's wrong then, sorry.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I think your idea was right, because the method is only for the SearchDisplayController. Should I add an else command for the normal TableView?